# Uncaught Error while running Sails in Production Mode and Dev is working fine

Tags: sails.js

I am trying run Sails Application in Production mode by setting NODE_ENV=production but my production.min.js file is giving Uncaught Reference error where it is running fine development  mode.

```
Uncaught Error: Must be an instanceof Promise.
    at new a (production.min.js:3)
    at Function.a.resolve (production.min.js:3)
    at Object.CcnG (production.min.js:26)
    at d (production.min.js:7)
    at Object.zUnb (production.min.js:86)
    at d (production.min.js:7)
    at Object.7 (production.min.js:20)
    at d (production.min.js:7)
    at c (production.min.js:7)
    at Array.b [as push] (production.min.js:7)
```

I an using angular frontend so placed angular build files like main.js in assets/js folder.

Comment: is there a difference between `config/env/development.js` and  `config/env/production.js`?

Comment: No it is same except few global custom variables